# JavaScript tables flicker on load/refresh. How can I avoid this happening?

Tags: javascript

I have had some successes integrating this code snippet with my data tables. The only problem is there seems to be a flicker of all the tables on screen when the page is loading or refreshing, before even entering any search/filter/query words. Have tried hide/show with CSS and variations of displaying results in JAVASCRIPT and HTML with no ultimate fix. I would love to know how to resolve this problem and with keeping mark.js highlight in effect.

JAVASCRIPT

```
var input, table, rows, markInstance;

window.onload = function init() {
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);

  clear();
}

function ContactsearchFX() {

  clear();

  if (input.value.length == 0) return;

  filterRows(input.value);
  highlightMatches(input.value);
}

        function clear() {
          markInstance.unmark();

         for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
       rows[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    function filterRows(text) {
  var part = text.toUpperCase();
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
var row = rows[i];
var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

if (td) {

  var content = td.innerText.toUpperCase();

  if (content.includes(part)) {
    row.style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}

function highlightMatches(text) {
   markInstance.mark(text);
}
```

CSS

```
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.hints {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

myInput:invalid~.hints {
  display: block;
}

mark {
    background: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1                                                    /mark.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
    Search Titles: 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required 
           onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" 
               placeholder="Search Titles" />

        <span class="hints">
      Hints: type "git", "bit", "forge" ...
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td> * DATA <TABLES> NESTED IN HERE *
</td>
    </tr>
      </table>
```

Ps have had no problems with mark.js

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: well onload table loads and than you hide all the rows. There will be a time when rows are visible until they are hidden. Seems like if you do not want to be viisble from the start than hide it by default.

Comment: Thanks Epascarello, have tried hide by default though then the filter displays no results what so ever.

Comment: Add this in the <head> section: `<style>html{visibility: hidden;opacity:0;}</style>` then add this as the last line in your css: `html { visibility: visible; opacity: 1;}`. It's a technique used to hide the Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC).

Comment: Thank you Iskandar, tried your quick fix but still getting the flicker on load/refresh.

Comment: Can you upload a working demo somewhere (JSBin, etc.) and share a link?